Error Overriding Request Params in ExpressJs
I am using express 4.19.2 (latest as of this writing)
This is the Request generic type decaration
interface ParamsDictionary {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface Request<
  P = core.ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = core.Query,
  Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals> {}

I am trying to override P or Params, so that I can refer the actual type in my route handler. However, I get this error
Type '(req: Request<ItemParam, unknown, ItemBody, unknown, JwtUser>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, unknown, ItemBody, ParsedQs, JwtUser>'
Types of property 'params' are incompatible. Property 'itemId' is missing in type 'ParamsDictionary' but required in type 'ItemParam'
Snippets from my code
interface ItemParam {
  itemId: string;
}

const myHandler = async (
    // ✅ No typescript error here
    req: Request<ItemParam, unknown, ItemBody, unknown, JwtUser>,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
  ): Promise<void> => {
   const { itemId } = req.params; // ✅ Can refer itemId
   const { amount } = req.body; // ✅ Can refer amount
};

// ❌ However, I get the error in the route
router.route('/:itemId').put(
  validate({
    params: {
      itemId: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  }),
  myHandler, // ❌ Error here as shown above
);

I don't get any ts error if I remove validate
// ✅ This works
router.route('/:itemId').put(
      myHandler,
    );

I also don't get error if I override my handler like this
// ✅ This works
Request<{ itemId: string }, unknown, PlaceBidItemBody, unknown, JwtUser>

I can resort to above as workaround. But can someone help me understand the issue or confirm if this is an express bug?
UPDATE / POSSIBLE SOLUTION
I fixed the ItemParam type to:
interface ItemParam {
  itemId: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}

I cannot/don't want to extend from ParamsDictionary bec it comes from express-server-static-code which is preincluded in express. As far as I know, it's not a good practice referring anything from packages you did not explicitly install.
Anyways, can someone help me understand why the original ItemParam is not readily compatible with ParamsDictionary?

what is the return type of validate?

@TalRofe validate(schema: schema, options?: EvOptions | undefined, joiRoot?: Joi.ValidationOptions | undefined): express.RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<...>> copied from vscode intellisense

Did some digging to understand and review the rules. And here are a few reminders for me:

itemId is a literal type. Not string type, not number type, but a literal type. By virtue, it is a string bec of the name itself, but it does not make it a string. Same goes with how we cannot just assign any string value to this type. For Example.


type Status = 'success' | 'failed'
const status1: Status = 'error'; ❌
const status2: Status = 'success'; ✅


It's so basic and I knew about this, but I guess not fully until now. Or most likely I was carried away as to how Body can accept an interface, but not Param (also Query). I wanted my code neat and clean and my interface/types reusable.

To lecture myself further, the reason behind the difference and limitation in types between Param, Query, Body lie with how browser works -- the property values will always be string unlike Body that can deliver a number, boolean and even null aside from string.

Param, the value of param id will always be treated as a string "1000678"

http://example.com/api/sample/:id
http://example.com/api/sample/1000678


Query, the value of query variable id will always be treated as a string

http://example.com/api/sample?id=1000678


Body via Post/Put, the value of id can be a number and will be treated as such

{
   "id": 1000678,
}


SOLUTION
Either ensures that the key will be of type string while retaining a strong type-ness of the interface.
interface ItemParam extends Record<string, string> {
  itemId: string;
}

interface ItemParam {
  itemId: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}

